# Uploading a form posted image buffer to Cloud Storage with Firebase Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

Here's my cloud function. It's supposed to get an http posted image and upload it to storage, returning the url.

```
exports.uploadImageToEditor = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
        const img = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(req.body));
        const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

        return bucket.file('blog/foo.jpg').save(img.data, { 
          resumable: false, 
          metadata: { 
            contentType: 'image/jpeg' 
          } 
        })
          .then(() => {
              return cors(req, res, () => {
                  res.status(200).send({ "url": bucket.file('foo.jpg').getSignedUrl()});
                });
            });
    });
```

This is how the image is actually sent in the client:

```
uploadImage(file, endPoint) {
        if (!endPoint) {
            throw new Error('Image Endpoint isn`t provided or invalid');
        }
        const                  formData = new FormData();
        if (file) {
            formData.append('file', file);
            const                  req = new HttpRequest('POST', endPoint, formData, {
                reportProgress: true
            });
            return this._http.request(req);
        }
        else {
            throw new Error('Invalid Image');
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is that Blob type?  It doesn't seem to be part of the Cloud Storage node API.  https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/

Comment: It's generated by a wysiwyg editor. I'm just trying to implement an endpoint for it with Firebase Functions: https://sibiraj-s.github.io/ngx-editor/additional-documentation/image-uploader.html

Comment: If it's not a type recognized by the SDK, it's not going to work.  You can't upload arbitrary object types - the SDK won't know how to deal with them.

Comment: I see... thanks anyways!

Comment: @DougStevenson I think I didn't explain myself correctly. It is a plain jpeg file. The function logs for the req.body something like <Buffer ff d8 ff e1 2c 57 45 78 ... >

Answer (score 8):

I think you're probably looking for the [save()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/File#save) method on `File` in the Admin SDK.

```
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket()
  .file('my-file.jpg').save(blob)
  .then(() => { /* ... */ });
```

Comment: I've tried to directly pass img.data (which is a buffer array) to the save method with the syntax you provided but now I'm getting TypeError: "listener" argument must be a function from Firebase Functions

Comment: Why does the save fuction return with a Promise<void>? How can I get back information about the uploaded file, for example its url?

Comment: but this method does not give me a download URL

Answer (score 3):

You can also get back information about the file this way.

```
export const uploadImage = async (destination: string, image: Buffer) => {
  const file = storage.bucket().file(destination);
  await file.save(image, { contentType: yourContentType });
  return file.publicUrl();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get a *permission error*, go to Firebase storage Rules and add this rule to allow to write in the directory :

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /blog/{anyPath=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write;
    }
  }
}
```